# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack

Hi I am going through webpack output management demo, but when I run 'npm run build' in the terminal this is what I get

[image]

[image]

src/print.js

```
export default function printMe() {
    console.log('I get called from print.js!');
  }
```

src/index.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import printMe from './print.js';

 function component() {
   const element = document.createElement('div');
   const btn = document.createElement('button');

  
  
   element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');


   btn.innerHTML = 'Click me and check the console!';
  btn.onclick = printMe;

  element.appendChild(btn);
  

   return element;
 }

 document.body.appendChild(component());
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
    print: './src/print.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  

};
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that since I copied and pasted the name, It appeared in my directory with quotes around it [image]